# Django Ninja API schema circular import error

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-ninja

I have `UserSchema`:

```py
# users/models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...


# users/schemas.py
from typing import List
from tasks.schemas import TaskSchema

class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    tasks: List[TaskSchema] = []

    class Config:
        model = User
        ...
```

...and `TaskSchema`:

```py
# tasks/models.py
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="tasks", on_delete=models.CASCASE)


# tasks/schemas.py
from users.schemas import UserSchema

class TaskSchema(ModelSchema):
    owner: UserSchema

    class Config:
        model = Task
        ...
```

But it throws:

```bash
ImportError: cannot import name 'TaskSchema' from partially initialized module 'tasks.schemas' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/myname/codes/django/ninja-api/tasks/schemas.py)
```

---

What I want to do is that I want to fetch:

1. `GET /api/todos` - a list of tasks with related owners
2. `GET /api/todos/{task_id}` - a task with owner
3. `GET /api/users/{user_id}` - a user with a list of owned tasks

---

Versions:

```
python = ^3.11
django = ^4.1.5
django-ninja = ^0.20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the name of the two models or file name is the same or not if that also does not work then tell them to make a model in the same file or add that one in the same file so circular data will not happen.

Hope this will help you.